# Getting "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'" error

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angularjs, spring-boot

I am getting below error while running my angular application:

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-CV4xui5ouJuzCdRbfqkCRTzT+J/DBWMVkyZjvjQCtdY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I have no error when I am running the angular app separately, but after I run a mvn clean package to create a jar file with the spring boot server, the error occurs when I am running the jar file. I am using `ngStyle` in my html file, not sure if this is the cause?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add this SHA sha256-CV4xui5ouJuzCdRbfqkCRTzT+J/DBWMVkyZjvjQCtdY= to your content security policy under default-src

Comment: fixed it by editing the backend configuration